# How to find the DOM element of a functional children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apparently this is not possible, but since I'm not a React expert I'd like to get a confirmation.

The usual way of getting the DOM element of a child is with:

```
render () {
    const child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    const cloned = React.cloneElement(child, {
        ref: this.someRef
    });
    return cloned;
}
```

The problem here is that according to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they
>   don’t have instances

Another option to find the DOM element could be using `React.findDOMNode()` but according to a comment from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4244) when trying to `React.findDOMNode(child)`:

> If you want to find one of your children's DOM nodes, you have to add
>   a ref first (using React.cloneElement) and then use that ref.

And we're back to the previous problem.

So, is it possible to find the DOM element of a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047063/direct-call-of-a-functional-component), this may be one of few acceptable cases for calling stateless component function directly:

```
function withRef(SFC) {
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => SFC({ref, ...props}));
}

...

render () {
  const child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
  const isFunctional = typeof child === 'function' &&
    (!child.prototype || !child.prototype.isReactComponent);

  if (isFunctional) {
    const Child = withRef(child.type);

    return <Child {...child.props} ref={this.someRef}/>;
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

This won't work if functional component's child cannot accept a ref, too.

In this form it's inefficient because a child will be re-rendered. Depending on what's the purpose, there may be better ways to achieve this. A component could be designed to receive a component to render as a prop instead of a child. Or if DOM element is needed for specific task like setting up DOM event listener, this may be done like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708063/3731501) .

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't work either because (like you said) no refs can used

Comment: Did you try it? withRef specifically allows to pass refs to stateless components. *this may be one of few acceptable cases for calling stateless component function directly*.