# Modify render function of external React component (with no access)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition

I have to use a react component that I cannot modify. It's from an external source, due to changes. This could also be a component from a npm package that I import. This is what it looks like, a simple button:

```
class Button extends React.Component {

 // ... more code above  
 render() {
  const { onClick, disabled, children} = this.props;

  return (
    <button className={this.getClasses()} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>
      {this.props.symbol && <Icon symbol={this.props.symbol} />}
      {children}
    </button>
  );

 }

}
```

How can I add some functionality with no access to the file (I can create my own component that extends the button)? For example, I want a `type` prop in there. I thought I can just create a `<ButtonExtend onClick={resetState} type="button />`.

How can I do this? Ideally I would like to make this even more flexible, so I can also do: `<ButtonExtend onClick={resetState} type="submit" name="extended button" />`.

I would expect the html to render all the properties from `<Button>` with my additional html attributes. So I want to use the functionality of the original  and my additional props. Or it this not even possible, to change the render method of another component, if the component doesn't make it possible?

Comment: Just extend your own class/component from `Button` and override its `render` method

Comment: you can't inject attributes into the button html element even decorating the component. You could subclass it and override the render method though, if still some reusable code remains in the original component.

Comment: @hindmost Is this not possible in a compositional kind of way?

Comment: @abidibo do you have an example? Not sure if I can follow

Comment: Sure it's possible in the same way as `Button` is extended from `React.Component`

Comment: @hindmost If possible, could you please provide some code example?

Answer (score 0):

Unless a component was designed for customization, there is no straightforward way to do this.

`Button` is an example of badly designed component because it doesn't accept additional props. An issue and PR could be submitted to the repository in order to address original problem.

In extended component, this can be fixed by passing props from extended component.

Parent `render` result could be modified:

```
class ButtonExtend extends Button {
 // ... more code above  
 render() {
  const button = super.render();
  const { symbol, children, ...props } = this.props;

  return React.cloneElement(button, {
    children: [
      symbol && <Icon symbol={symbol} />,
      ...children
    ],
    ...props
  });
}
```

If an element that needs to be modified is nested, this may become messy and result in unnecessarily created elements.

A cleaner way is to paste `render` in extended component and modify it:

```
class ButtonExtend extends Button {
 // ... more code above  
 render() {
  const { symbol, children, ...props } = this.props;

  return (
    <button className={this.getClasses()} {...props}/>
      {symbol && <Icon symbol={symbol} />}
      {children}
    </button>
  )
 }
}
```

This way it can be used as

```
<ButtonExtend onClick={resetState} type="submit" name="extended button" />
```

Comment: if component is external (from an NPM package, IE) and a particular prop is not expected, cloning an element and merge props could be useless.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not expected'? onClick, etc are expected. This will result in re-rendered button with desired props. Try it yourself.

Comment: Him is trying to get a different render, so events and standard props may be not enough

Comment: I downvoted because React Devs promote composition over inheritance and your solution involves inheritance even if React has a pattern to manage cases as this. "At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies." ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I'm very aware of composition over inheritance. React promotes composition where it's justified, not as a dogma that should be blindly followed. Overriding `render` result is edge case that cannot be efficiently solved with composition alone. You obviously didn't try your own answer. Try to do this with HOC as you suggest and see what happens. You will end up extending a class any way and calling component's `render` method from HOC any way like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705522) in order to augment it  (see `super.render()` part in question code).

Comment: @estus hi thanks for the wisdom, you said I should submit a PR. I will do this no matter which approach I take now, thanks! How should that person design its component, so that I can add some more props?

Comment: @phifa `<button>` should accept the rest of the props as `{...this.props}` like in the second snippet. Notice that you don't need to pass similarly named props like `onClick`, `children` explicitly, they will be passed this way. This may be different for other components, but for `Button` this is so.

Comment: I think this is a really bad implementation. It's from storybook, these are components that I have to use. I added `{...this.props}`to the `<Button>` and now everything gets put rendered to the actual html button. So not just type="button", which is good, but also internal information props like `symbol="trashcan"`... I updated the code in the original post, so you see where the symbol is rendered. It's an icon in the button. This should not be rendered to html attribute of the <button>

Comment: @phifa In case don't you need to pass all props, you need to filter out those ones that don't need to be passed. This is done with destructuring. I updated the answer to show how `children` is handled in this case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although public methods and properties of a component are accessible by `refs` (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) the pattern are you looking for is High Order Components (HOC, https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: I could not find a HOC example that modifies the render method like I need it. Do you have an example?

Comment: What props do you need and what render do you expect ?

Comment: I want a type prop in there for example. So I can say type=„button“ or type=„submit“. I expect a simple button to be rendered.