# Inject markup into existing Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to inject markup into existing components.

This is an easy example:

```html
<!-- Arbitrary component X -->
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- I want a headline here -->
    foo!
  </div>
</template>
```

I know that I can achieve this by inserting a `<slot/>` and then using `<X><h1>Hello world!</h1></X>`. However, I want to do it dynamically **without** editing the original component.

So here's my idea using a higher-order-component:

```
import X from '~/components/X';
import injectHeadline from '~/hoc/injectHeadline.js';

export default {
  components: {
    X: injectHeadline(X, 'Hello world!')
  }
}
```

with

```
<!-- injectHeadline.js -->
export default (component, headline) => Vue.component({
    render(createElement) {
        let result = createElement(component);

        <!-- (*) somehow insert <h1>{{ headline }}</h1> here. How? -->

        return result;
    }
})
```

However, I had no luck manipulating the render result in `(*)`. I tried fiddling with `result.context.$children`, but that leads nowhere.
Any idea?

Comment: As a workaround, I found `export default (component, title) => ({
    extends: component,
    mounted() {
        let titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
        titleElement.textContent = title;
        this.$el.insertBefore(titleElement, this.$el.firstChild);
    }
});`, but this works only on the client-side. I'd prefer the `render` phase.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Vue.compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) function that compiles a template string into a render function.

Comment: @YomS. Thanks. I considered that. But I have trouble determining the original component's markup from within the `render` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use the same approach for template extension as in React, to modify a hierarchy of VNodes before they are rendered to DOM, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53087481/3731501):

```
export default (WrappedComponent, headline) => Vue.component({
  extends: WrappedComponent,
  render(h) {
    const elements = this.$options.extends.render.call(this, h);
    elements.children.unshift(<h1>{headline}</h1>));
    return elements;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I neded! For some reason it works only if I return a config object without `Vue.component`, so I ended up with `export default (WrappedComponent, headline) => ({
    extends: WrappedComponent,
    render(createElement) {
        const elements = this.$options.extends.render.call(this, createElement);
        elements.children.unshift(createElement('h1', headline));
        return elements;
    }
});
`

Answer (score 0):

simple as that

```
<script>
export default {
  functional: true,
  render: function(createElement, context) {
    return createElement("div", context.slots().default);
  }
};
</script>
```

btw i set it to functional for performance (there is no need for vnode in this case)

in your code you could do it like this

```
let result = createElement(component,this.$slots.default);
```