# React global click track handler

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and working on a legacy codebase. Am wondering if we can write a global button  click handler for click tracking.

The jQuery equivalent of this would be something like,

```
utilities.js :

 var subscribeForClickTracking = function() {
        $( "button" ).click((event) => { console.log($(event.target).html()) })
        $( "p" ).click((event) => { console.log($(event.target).html()) })
  }
```

In all the html files, will add reference to utiliies.js and this snippet of code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 subscribeForClickTracking();
});
```

I have surfed about this and reached similar so questions, like 
[Higher Order React Component for Click Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705522/higher-order-react-component-for-click-tracking)
and https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-track-user-interactions-in-your-react-app-b82f0bc4c7ff/

But these solutions involve modifying  the button's implementation, which would lead to huge change. (For a html form with 50+ buttons).

Is there an alternate approach to achieve something similar to the above jQuery approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do that. The reason is that React prevents you from doing global things to avoid side effects.
I think the proper React way would be to create your own Button component.

First create a new component :
`export default Button = (props) => <button ...props />`
Then, you can import and use Button instead of button in any component.
Then in your Button component, you can override your onClick method like this :

```
    <button
    ...props
    onClick={() => {
    // doWhatYouWantHere;
    props.onClick()
    />
```

However, as React is JavaScript, you can still use vanilla JavaScript to attach an event to every button