# ReactJs: How to create a wrapper component that would execute certain code when clicked and render the child component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, redux

I am trying to create a generic React component that I could wrap around any component and that would execute some code when it's clicked:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.onElementClicked = this.onElementClicked.bind(this);
  }
  onElementClicked() {
    // CODE TO BE EXECUTED WHEN WRAPPER ELEMENT IS LICKED
  }
  render() {
    const {child_component}=this.props
    return (
      <span
        onClick={() => {
          this.onElementClicked();
        }}
      >
        {child_component}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

And this how I'd use it:

```
  <WrapperComponent
    component={<Button>Test</Button>}
  ></WrapperComponent>
```

This works perfectly fine.
However, I don't feel that it's right to follow this approach. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
  <WrapperComponent>
        <Button>Test</Button>
      </WrapperComponent>
```

So that all I have to do is literally wrap whichever element I want with `WrapperComponent` and achieve the same result.
Is that possible?

Comment: maybe have a look at render props? https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: See if you can leverage props.children - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it

Comment: using HOC?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705522/higher-order-react-component-for-click-tracking

Comment: props.children did the work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?
https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

you might be able to access the child component using props.children